# python3 jsonrpclib sends two different conclicting Content-type header fields

Tags: python-3.x, lighttpd, json-rpc

I have been upgrading some Python 2 scripts to Python 3. I used 2to3 to refactor the code. Running with python3, I get an exception. I was able to reproduce the problems with just three lines of code;

```
import jsonrpclib
p = jsonrpclib.Server("http://r195/cgi-bin/streamscape_api")
print(p.nodeid())
```

With python2, it works:

```
$ python rpc.py 
[u'3011']
```

When I run the exact same code with Python3, I get this exception:

```
$ python3 rpc.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "rpc.py", line 6, in <module>
  print(p.nodeid())
 File "/home/kory/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 265, in __call__
  return self.__send(self.__name, kwargs)
 File "/home/kory/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 212, in _request
  response = self._run_request(request)
 File "/home/kory/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 226, in _run_request
  response = self.__transport.request(
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1153, in request
  return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1183, in single_request
  raise ProtocolError(
xmlrpc.client.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for r195/cgi-bin/streamscape_api: 400 Bad Request>
```

Using WireShark, I captured the traffic between the python script and the webserver. The only difference was tje header. With python2, thid is the header sent to the webserver;

```
Host: r195
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: jsonrpclib/0.1 (Python 2.7.18)
Content-Type: application/json-rpc
```

With python3, the header is:

```
Host: r195
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml
User-Agent: jsonrpclib/0.1 (Python 3.8.10)
Content-Type: application/json-rpc
```

Notice that python3, sends two "Content-Type" headers. Using curl

to build a request packet the headers, the problem is the "Content-Type: text/xml". Sending the request with curl without that content type, works correctly.

Just to be sure, as a test, I commented out [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/xmlrpc/client.py#L1282) from xmlrpc/client.py, and the script now works with python3. But commenting out that line is not a viable solution. I believe the webserver is running lighttpd 1.4.54.

Part of the issue is due to the way the xmlrpc.py has changed from python2 to python3. the send_content() used to be the one adding content-type header and send_request would just send the request in 2.

In 3, xmlrpc adds content-type in send_request() which is semantically incorrect. So when jsonrpclib overloads send_content() it adds the extra content-type header.

This project: https://github.com/tcalmant/jsonrpclib/tree/master/jsonrpclib corrects this by overloading send_request() as well and does not add the content-type header, which is correctly done in the overloaded send_content. So using this would fix this issue. However the underlying issue of why lighttpd fails when there are repeated content-type is weird. If there is no answer, we can go ahead and ignore, since most clients will not do this.

What I would like to know is that is this a python3 jdonrpclib bug or a lighthttpd bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to know is that is this a python3 jdonrpclib bug or a lighthttpd bug?

Sending two (or more) different Content-Type headers with a request is definitely a bug in the python library/libraries interaction.

> However the underlying issue of why lighttpd fails when there are repeated content-type is weird.

No, it is not weird.  lighttpd intentionally rejects duplicated Content-Type in the request, and has done so since lighttpd 1.3.12 (released in 2005).  Those duplicated Content-Type headers conflict with one another in your invalid request.

You can set lighttpd.conf `debug.log-request-header-on-error = "enable"` and lighttpd will report the following in the lighttpd error log for the invalid request: "duplicate Content-Type header -> 400"

[Edit] For reference:
RFC7231 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content

[RFC 7231 Appendix D. Collected ABNF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#appendix-D) defines `Content-Type = media-type`, allowing a single `media-type`, not a variable number.  As a consequence, duplicated `Content-Type` headers are not permitted by the spec.